# Add empty layers to Feature Service with ArcGIS Python API

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, feature-service, arcgis-collector, arcgis-python-api

I would like to create a number of Feature Services. Each Feature Service should contain 15-20 layers. There is no data yet, as I would like to create these for data collection with ArcGIS Collector.  From an excel sheet, I know what attributes belong to each layer.

It is easy to create empty feature services with the ArcGIS Python API. But I cannot find a solution for adding layers (with specific attributes and geometry types etc.) to these empty feature services.

Where can I find an example? Or more documentation?

Comment: Do you have to do it using the Python API? Where will the services be stored? In AGOL, on Portal or a GIS data Server?

Comment: Everything is up in AGOL.

Reason being: I need to setup several webmaps containing tens of layers each, depending on data in an excel sheet. I am not going to manually create all these feature services.